# JMH: Buggy output in a benchmark

Tags: java, jmh

[image: Buggy output]

In the above output from JMH benchmark, you can see that some averages are not numeric text. Is that a bug in JMH or my benchmark?

Comment: It looks as if JMH is writing some Unicode characters but your terminal window is not using the same encoding as JMH. Try redirecting the output to a file, then open the file in a decent text editor that allows you to specify the input encoding, and see what it shows.

Comment: @k314159 You were right. Adding some encoding configuration to netbeans.conf solved the problem.